# Ubuntu 20.04 laptop screen problems -- birghtness can not be changed anymore

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness, 20.04

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 (Gnome 3.36.1) I have some problems with the screen of my laptop (Clevo N151ZU, i7 8565U):

- I can't change the screen brigthness with my keyboard (Fn + F8/9)
- I can't change the screen brightness with the menu in the right top corner (where you can change the volume, shutdown the pc, etc.)
- I can't change the screen brightness in the Gnome settings
  -My laptop display is shown as "Unknown Display" in the Gnome display settings
- I can't change the Hz and the resolution (only avaiable option is 1920x1080) in the Gnome display settings
  -xbacklight is installed, the commands xbacklight -set 0, xbacklight -set 100 do nothing
- When I close the lid of my laptop, it doesn't go to standby (I set the option "go to standby, when lid is closed" in the Gnome tweak tool)
- The screen stays black, when I wake the laptop up from the standby (keyboard lights turn on, etc.)

On boot I get the error message:

```
i915: `' invalid for parameter `enable_dpcd_backlight
```

I tried it with these options in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor, acpi_backlight=video, acpi_backlight=native
```

(with a `sudo update-grub` and a reboot after it, of course), didn't change anything.

I installed the `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, no differences.

Some system information:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL core profile version string"
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.4
```

`ls /sys/class/backlight/` returns nothing.

```
$ sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/tuxedo_keyboard/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:3a:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:3a:00.0/leds/phy0-led/max_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/hw_changes_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
/sys/module/tuxedo_keyboard/parameters/brightness
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with my Tuxedo laptop (slightly different model by Clevo).
I just found that the syntax for `enable_dpcd_backlight` changed with the kernel version used in 20.04 (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight)).

Just change the corresponding line in `/etc/modprobe.d/tuxedo-i915.conf` to
`options i915 enable_dpcd_backlight=1` and reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still get the same error message on boot, but everything works!