# Ubuntu does not startup anymore with "i915 invalid parameters enable_dpcd_backlight" error messages

Tags: boot, i915

Since yesterday my dual-boot laptop does not start anymore with an error message:

```
i915: ' invalid for parameter enable_dpcd_backlight'

hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
```

Anyone has an idea, what I could do to get my system to startup again?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.In the grub menu hover over the **Ubuntu** entry and then press ```E``` to open up the text editor.Add the command line option ```i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=0``` at the end of the line beginning with the command ```linux```.Then press ```Ctrl+X``` to boot.If that doesn't help try setting it to ```1```.The default value for that option however in the intel's **i915** driver is **false** , so the first one should work if it has been worked before.

Comment: Check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237334/ubuntu-20-04-laptop-screen-problems also.

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing `i915.enable_dpcd_backlight=0` did the job. Now it works again.